# storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myIdentifier" shows blank view controller

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, uilocalnotification

I am making an application which shows a UILocalNotification and when user clicks on the notification, the app will show a new ViewController (designed in Storyboard) which doesn't have any segue from anywhere in my application.

To detect if the user has clicked on the notification I am doing the following in `didReceiveLocalNotification` :

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *checkListVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyCheckListVC"];
self.window.rootViewController = checkListVC;
```

So when user clicks on the notification, above code initiatizes my view controller (lets call it *CheckListVC*) which has the identifier "MyCheckListVC".
This CheckListVC has tableView, whose delegate and dataSource methods get called (`numberOfRowsInSection` & `cellForRowAtIndexPath`) when the view controller is initialized. But the problem is the simulator shows blank screen when CheckListVC is initialized instead of showing tableView.

I am not able to debug it because I don't even know where the problem is. The view controller gets initialized properly and all the delegate/dataSource methods are getting called properly, but the screen goes blank.

Comment: did you call `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible]` after you set your rootViewController, this could be the problem.

Comment: Yes I did call `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible]` but it doesn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to assign identifier to UIStoryboard.. 
1.select storyboard
2.assign the identifier name in "MyCheckListVC" in Identity inspector ..

check this image for clarity..

[image] [image]

follow these steps and try.. i think this will work.. :)